# laravel -> orderBy and GroupBy how to use in query

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

```
 $followupschedule=CustomerFollowupcallSchedule::where('coordinator_id', '=', Session::get('userid'))              
                ->orderBy('call_date', 'DESC')
                ->groupBy('lead_id')
                ->get();
```

I was using this to query from a table. When I use OrderBy it works correctly, but when i use GroupBy to the 'lead_id', it groups, but the OrderBy no longer works; only the top row with lead_id is getting fetched, not the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group by` and `order by` on different columns don't walk in hand, the database just doesn't know how to handle it.

It is possible though, it seems like you want the latest call_date for every lead_id:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `table`
    WHERE
        `coordinator_id` = 'fubar'
    ORDER BY
        `call_date` DESC
) AS temp
GROUP BY
    temp.`lead_id`
```

This way the subquery is selecting all data, order by the call_date.
The wrapping query grabs all that data, groups by lead_id, and this will (probably) retrieves the latest call_date.